# Copying Weights using NetTrain in Mathematica

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, scripting

I would like to implement the PPO algorithm - Reinforcement Learning - in Mathematica. And for that, I need to be able to copy network weights from say subnetwork NN1 to subnetwork NN2 as an update and as a part of the training process.

Is doing this possible in Mathematica? maybe my question can be split into two parts:

1. how can I copy weights?
2. how can I do that as a part of the training process, i.e. using NetTrain?

Answer (score 1):

RNNs have ports "State" (all) and "CellState" (LSTM only).

```
NetGraph[
 {
  BasicRecurrentLayer[8],
  BasicRecurrentLayer[8]
  },
 {
  NetPort[1, "State"] -> NetPort[2, "State"]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

With `ConvolutionLayer` and `LinearLayer` it's more complicated. They have no ports other than "Input" and "Output". We can copy and paste weights. But I do not know how to do this in `NetTrain` without breaking the training loop.

```
conv = ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "Input" -> {1, Automatic, Automatic}] // NetInitialize;
w = NetExtract[conv, "Weights"];
b = NetExtract[conv, "Biases"];
convNew = ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "Weights" -> w, "Biases" -> b]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. I have done a lot more research since posting this question, and it seems that there is no way to copy and paste weight from one net to another during the training. Unfortunately NetTake, NetReplacePart, NetExtract, and all other Mathematica net commands all give you a new copy of the net. Like you mentioned, convNew is a new net, not an updated one...